# Game Programming in C

Tags: c, windows

I have only have basic knowledge of C, and now I want to expand ot. I want to study 2D game programming in C. Is it that a possibility? Is there an engine I may use?

Comment: It is possible, have a look at http://www.libsdl.org/. This is a cross-platform library that can handle your input, audio and screen.

Comment: "I know all C basics" - then surely you can build a Google scraper using libcurl? (Don't forget to [test your knowledge](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4960980/C_exercises.txt) when you think you "know C". Then realize that [you didn't, really](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4960980/C_exercises_solutions.txt).)

Comment: @H2CO3; Is that your test paper?

Comment: Write some awesome ASCII-art games if you "know C".

Comment: @haccks Yes, it is. :) You can find it in my bio.

Comment: @H2CO3; I did that already :)

Comment: @H2CO3; You have not asked how many of them I answered ;)

Comment: Of course! This guy does a 1 week seminar Gamecrash (which I attended) and recently posted his experience of creating a game in 1 week, Spacecrash all code posted and explained: http://jonbho.net/

Comment: Anyone remember rogue? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(video_game)

Comment: Not an answer, but an advice: if you have no other programming experience than your "basic C", please do yourself a favor and start with some easier task. Writing games is not so easy as it may seem, and C is not easy either. It would be better for you to start with a simpler programming language. [Lua](http://www.lua.org) could be one. It is extensively used for game programming and [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/) is a nice environment for building 2D games based on Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [SDL Library](http://www.libsdl.org/):

> Simple DirectMedia Layer is a cross-platform development library designed to provide low level access to audio, keyboard, mouse, joystick, and graphics hardware via OpenGL and Direct3D. SDL is written in C, works natively with C++.

So you can use it with both C++ and C.

Likewise, you can also take a look at the [SFML Library](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) (Which is native for C++, but has bindings for C as well):

> SFML provides a simple interface to the various components of your PC, to ease the development of games and multimedia applications. It is composed of five modules: system, window, graphics, audio and network.

Personally I would suggest SFML more, since it seems to have better support for OpenGL and personally is easier to program in.